# Insert user input into array then insert into sqlite database

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, sqlite

Got an assignment due in three months, thought I'd make a start today learning and experimenting with PHP so forgive me if I'm sloppy.

*I am trying to create a simple form  that takes user input and sends it to an sqlite database.*

I have a version that creates and connects fine and inserts data with predefined data in my array. I'd like to remove that data and have three input fields in html named 'first name', 'last name' and 'age' that gets inputted into my array named `$data` which is then sent of to my sqlite database. Next I plan on adding my input fields but I am struggling to understand how they will work and how the data will be formatted in the array appropriately. Some suggestions of methods of doing this would be appreciated (ignore my second `foreach` loop, I just wanted to view my data onscreen).

Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Data Input</title>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('sqlite:mydb.sqlite3');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
             firstName VARCHAR(30),
             lastName VARCHAR(30),
             age INTEGER)"
             );

    $data = array(
            array('firstName' => 'Billy',
                  'lastName' => 'Bob',
                  'age' => '18'),
            array('firstName' => 'Bill',
                  'lastName' => 'Bob',
                  'age' => '32')
            );

    $insert = "INSERT INTO test (firstName, lastName, age)
           VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :age)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($insert);

    $stmt->bindParam('firstName', $firstName);
    $stmt->bindParam('lastName', $lastName);
    $stmt->bindParam('age', $age);

foreach ($data as $m) {
    $firstName = $m['firstName'];
    $lastName = $m['lastName'];
    $age = $m['age'];

    $stmt->execute();


}
    $result = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM test');
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo "First Name: " . $row['firstName'] . " ";
        echo "Last Name: " . $row['lastName'] . " ";
        echo "Age: " . $row['age'] . "<br>" . " ";
}

    $dbh = null;

}
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        // Print PDOException message
        echo $e->getMessage();
}        
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you asking how PHP form results can be accessed on the landing page?

Comment: I'm asking how to gather user input from a html input field which when submitted is sent into the $data array which  then  submits to my sqlite database. Sorry if i'm vague, hard explaining what i'm trying to do. To be more specific, would something like "array('firstName' => $firstName," work? but then how do i save the user input into that variable from the field upon submitting it.

Comment: If you want an easier way to debug tour output than writing loops and echos every time, try PHP dBug (http://dbug.ospinto.com/). It can save a lot of hair pulling... especially with more complicated arrays/objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a form that will create results in the same format as your $data field (you can also generate this using PHP, or dynamically using jQuery) :

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST'){
?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="firstName[0]"/>
        <input type="text" name="lastName[0]"/>
        <input type="number" name="age[0]" min="1" max="99"/>

        <input type="text" name="firstName[1]"/>
        <input type="text" name="lastName[1]"/>
        <input type="number" name="age[1]" min="1" max="99"/>

        <input type="text" name="firstName[2]"/>
        <input type="text" name="lastName[2]"/>
        <input type="number" name="age[2]" min="1" max="99"/>

        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php
}else{

    unset($_POST['submit']);
    $data=$_POST;

    // ... now do your database insert here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, working great. Sorry for being vague. Guessing you ment $data=$_POST; right?